# Setup UDT library on XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, udp-data-transfer

I have a Macbook Pro Retina with OS X Yosemite installed. I need to get UDT library (see http://sourceforge.net/projects/udt/) working on my environment. I downloaded the most recent version (4.11), extracted it, then ran

```
make -e os=OSX arch=AMD64
```

as per instructions [here](http://udt.sourceforge.net/udt4/doc/make.htm). I then moved the udt.h file from the src folder to my /usr/include folder, the udt.dylib to my /usr/lib folder. Then I added -I/usr/include to my "Other C++ flags" setting in my Xcode project, and "-L/usr/lib" to my "Other linker flags" setting.

When including

```
#include <udt.h>
```

Everything works fine (it looks like it can find the file). But when I also add -ludt to my "Other linker flags" setting, I get

```
ld: library not found for -ludt
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.